# How to fix blank line issue in Pandas with Selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I'm extracting the links from a page and saving it in an excel spreadsheet.

I have a problem, with the code, it skips a line to save the next link, as shown in the image below.

[image]

```
grupos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_7hkg")
for elm in grupos:
        link = elm.get_attribute("href")
        #link = elm.get_attribute("href").replace("m.","")
        print(link)
        links.append(link) 
        data = {'URL': links} 
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_excel(r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\LinksGrupo.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
        print(df)
```

Comment: Are those lines really blank?  I see a zero on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a list just use double colons
before store into the pandas dataframe

```
links=links[0::2]# get the odd number index element from the list
```

or for even number

```
links=links[1::2]
```

Comment: because i dont have your webpage,but yeah if you want to try by XPATH instead of by class name maybe can get rid of those blank elements

Comment: kaispace30098, thank you, it worked